# shared library: ubuntu/macosx

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

Why compiling

```
extern "C" {

bool foo();

}

void call_foo()
{
    foo();
}
```

using

```
g++ -fPIC -c -o test.o test.cpp
g++ test.o -shared -o test
```

gives me undefined symbols error under macos x and no error under ubuntu?